# Powershell issue when using mkdir command

Tags: powershell

I've encountered a strange issue with powershell. When calling the mkdir command with a powershell var it appears that powershell appends to the variable, although this only occurs if inside a function call.

I have the following sample code.

```
function TestStuff($test) {
    Write-Host "Called with parameter: $test"
    $newPath = Join-Path "C:\testy\" $test
    mkdir $newPath
    # It's ok here
    Write-Host "New path is: $newPath"
    return $newPath;
}

$myNewPath = TestStuff "testVar"
# It's been doubled up here
Write-Host "Returned from function it is: $myNewPath"
```

This produces the following output

```
Called with parameter: testVar
New path is: C:\testy\testVar
Returned from function it is: C:\testy\testVar C:\testy\testVar
```

Buried within a powershell script this issue was tricky to spot. Is anyone able to explain this behaviour. The eventual solution got re-written so it was not a function call. The other alternative was to pipe the output of `mkdir` to null as follows: `mkdir $myPath > null` Although this produces a file named null on file system but didn't seem to fiddle with the `$myPath` var.

Comment: MKDIR is an alias for the PS command New-Item - most commands of this nature produce an output whcih if you don;t want you need to supress.
You don't have to specify a returned item - thus changing "RETURN $newPath" to RETURN and leaving the MKDIR command alone would have worked also.

Comment: @Scepticalist - or you can drop the entire `return` line? That said, I prefer the `out-null` solution and be explicit about what you return.

Comment: Well yes indeed, you very rarely need return, I'd mostly create a custom object or select the properties to return in all but the simplest situations

Answer (score 0):

> I've encountered a strange issue with powershell

No, you've come to learn the true nature of PowerShell.

In PowerShell, any output from any value expression "bubbles up" to the caller, including the output from the `mkdir` call:

```
PS C:\> $myNewPath = TestStuff "testVar"
PS C:\> $myNewPath.Count
2
PS C:\> $myNewPath[0].GetType() # the output from `mkdir` is a DirectoryInfo object

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                  
True     True     DirectoryInfo                            System.IO.FileSystemInfo  

PS C:\> $myNewPath[1].GetType() # this is the string you `return`d:

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                  
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

---

To fix your function, either suppress the output from `mkdir` with `Out-Null` or by assigning it to `$null`:

```
mkdir $newPath |Out-Null
# or
$null = mkdir $newPath
# or 
[void]( mkdir $newPath )
```

... or simply pass through the results directly from `mkdir`:

```bsh
function Test-Stuff {
    param($test)

    Write-Host "Called with parameter: $test"
    $newPath = Join-Path "C:\testy" $test

    # No output suppression, output value will be returned to the caller
    mkdir $newPath

    # Let's ensure that the last call actually succeeded
    if($?){
        Write-Host "New path is: $newPath"
    }
}
```